# Issues when installing python package from github (google/protobuf)

Tags: package-management, python

Note: I am just starting out with ubuntu and python, I have extensive coding experience in other languages under windows.

So, I want to install this package:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/python
I tried installing it in the following way: I tried downloading the code in this repository and then installing it. So first I downloaded the code using SVN:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/google/protobuf/trunk/python
```

Then I tried installing it using:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

This gave the following output:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating protobuf.egg-info
writing requirements to protobuf.egg-info/requires.txt
writing protobuf.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing namespace_packages to protobuf.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
writing top-level names to protobuf.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to protobuf.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'protobuf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'protobuf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'google/protobuf/internal/*_pb2.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'google/protobuf/internal/*.proto'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*_test.py' found under directory 'google'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*_test.proto' found under directory 'google'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'unittest*_pb2.py' found under directory 'google'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'protobuf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
Generating google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py...
Can't find required file: ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

Manual inspection of my folders and of the original github confirmed that "descriptor.proto" was indeed not present. I did find lines 128-129 of setup.py:

```
# Generate necessary .proto file if it doesn't exist.
generate_proto("../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto")
```

So, I assume this file should have been created automatically, but wasn't for some reason. Does anyone know why?

edit:
I also tried just using:

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

This gave similarly:

```
running build
running build_py
Generating google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py...
Can't find required file: ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

edit 2: I now pulled the entire repository and rerun

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

This gave as output:

```
running build
running build_py
Generating google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py...
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:381:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:381:12: Expected field name.
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:439:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:439:12: Expected field name.
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:537:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:537:12: Expected field name.
```

The corresponding lines in the descriptor.proto file are:
line 381:

```
reserved 38;
```

line 439:

```
reserved 8;  // javalite_serializable
```

line 537:

```
reserved 4;  // removed jtype
```

These are also the only times this "reserved [number]" syntax is used, so I think this syntax might be the cause of the problem somehow. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Did you try setup.py build or similar?

Comment: Yes,  this gave similar results. See edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got the answer from someone else, here is what finally worked for me:

First get a clean download of all the code (not only the python part as I initially did):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
```

Then install some dependencies and compile:

```
$ cd protobuf/
$ apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip
```

Then follow src/README.md:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
```

Then install the python part, as described in python/README.md

```
$ cd python
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py test
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only pulled part of the repository (`protobuf/python`), but the installation is looking for files in another directory (`protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`)

So just pull in the complete repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
```

Then:

```
$ cd protobuf/python
```

And follow the installation instructions in `README.md`.

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to help me a step further. Unfortunately I am still having problems. Could you take a look at the latest edit of my main post?

Comment: Maybe using a release is easier than compiling yourself: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases